# Server (java) can't receive XML from client (c#) with SSL connection

Tags: java, c#, xml, ssl

i'm trying to sending XML from client to server. I using this `using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;` and got Exception called in `AuthenticateClient`. The exception is

> AutenticationException was caught, A call to SSPI failed, see inner
>   exception.

this is my code :

```
public static SslStream OpenSSL(string _IP, int _port)
{
    try
    {
        TcpClient client = new TcpClient(_IP, _port);

        // Create a secure stream
        SslStream sslStream = new SslStream(client.GetStream(), false,
                    new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(ValidateServerCertificate), null);

        if (sslStream != null)
        {
            sslStream.AuthenticateAsClient(_IP);
        }

        return sslStream;
    }
    catch (Exception _e)
    {
        Util.Log.Track(Config.System.LogMode.UTIL, "Comms.Handler.OpenSSL: exception = " + _e.ToString());
        return null;
    }
}
```

I can connect to the server, but the server won't receive the XML. I'm stuck here for 2 days, is anyone knows whats wrong with this problem?

**note** : I use VS2010 (client) and Eclipse Mars for linux (server)

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this C# code

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback =
    ((sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true);
```

It ignores the errors of ssl validation

Then try another approach
Change it

```
if (sslStream != null)
{
    sslStream.AuthenticateAsClient(_IP);
}
```

to this

```
X509Certificates.X509Certificate2Collection xc = new X509Certificates.X509Certificate2Collection();
sslStream.AuthenticateAsClient(_IP, xc, Security.Authentication.SslProtocols.Tls, false);
```

Actually,I'm not sure about SslProtocols flags. Maybe `SslProtocols.Tls | SslProtocols.Ssl3`

If it doesn't help, I don't have any idea :)

Comment: thanks for answering. but its not work, the server still not receive the XML